# Android: Image Processing Library(Alternative for openCV)

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing

I am looking for an image processing library which can be used as an alternative for OpenCV
The tasks i would like to perform are
1)Convert image into a text form which can be manipulated as can be done with Mat in OpenCV and vice versa
2)Image Compression algorithms which can help me compress images

Comment: This policy is totally nonsense! Questions asking for advice on the best libraries to solve a specific problem are important, legit, and helpful for others, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this library

1. [OpenFrameworks for Android](http://openframeworks.cc/)
2. [OpenIMAJ](http://openimaj.org/)
3. [Google Android Vision API](https://developers.google.com/vision/)

I would recommend OpenFrameworks, install open frameworks for android studio http://openframeworks.cc/setup/android-studio/  and openframeworks android examples https://github.com/openframeworks/openFrameworks/tree/master/examples/android

or you can use Microsoft Cognitive services, new alternative for computer vision, ocr, ai etc.

https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/computer-vision-api , android examples https://github.com/Microsoft/ProjectOxford-ClientSDK/tree/master/Vision/Android

Android vision api examples https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision